# Anti-commutation relation for gamma matrices; when/why did the definition change?

Tags: metric-tensor, dirac-matrices, anticommutator

The anti-commutation relation defining gamma matrices is presently given by
$$\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu = 2g^{\mu\nu}$$
where appears the matric tensor (see for instance the previous [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394193/proof-of-the-anti-commutation-relation-for-gamma-matrices-from-dirac-equation)).
However, going back to the  [the "founding" 1928 paper of Dirac](https://doi.org/10.1098%2Frspa.1928.0023) we find a definition in terms of the Kronecker delta
$$\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu + \gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu = 2\delta_{\mu\nu}$$
which is also the definition given by Pauli in his [1936 study](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHP_1936__6_2_109_0/) of the mathematical properties of these matrices.
This implies a slight redefinition of the gamma matrices; notably, with the signature $(+---)$ the spatial part should be multiplied by imaginary *i*.
Does anybody know when the redefinition of these gamma matrices occurred and what was the motivation ?

Comment: "What was the motivation?" Realizing how stupid $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ looks in relativity, I guess.

Comment: This is actually more a question for the stack exchange on History of Science and Mathematics.

Comment: Do you understand the transition from the [timelike interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) of $(t,ix,iy,iz)$ of the early days to our present West-coast one of $(t,x,y,z)$? γ matrices parallel vectors.